# What is the proper way of calling a function of a same class without using objects in java?

Tags: java, function, class, object

How do I call a function of the same class in java without using an object?

I tried this but got an error:

> 'non-static method facti(int) cannot be referenced from a static context' 
>           System.out.print(facti(number));

```
public class Facto {
    int i, fact =1;
     int facti(int num){
        if(num == 0){
            System.out.print("For Zero ");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        for (i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number for factorial : ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        Facto f1 = new Facto();
        System.out.println(f1.facti(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that all that is wrapped in a class declaration similar to `public class Facto { ... }` then your code works fine for me.  Java IS a Object Oriented Language, this means just about everything is a object, so you need to start with one

Comment: The answer is in your error. Make the method `static`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure it needs to be, since they use `Facto f1 = new Facto();` and `f1.facti(number)` and if you take the code and wrap it in a proper class declaration it works, something else is missing

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was addressing the question in the title, if you're going to call a function of the same class without using an instance of that class then the function must be `static`. As for OOP, you are of course correct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, it's some what confusing :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, my guess is that the code posted is not the code that generated the error that was posted. There is no `fi.` in the error.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to solve this error by making something `static`, but this is the exception; your `fact` is a *pure function* (depends only on its inputs and has no side effects), so it does not need to be associated with an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't.
Your main method is 'static' it only can call other static methods (in the same class) or methods of an object. So you either can make "facti" static, too. Or you create an object: Facto f = new Facto(); f.facti(13); and call facti on that object.

Answer (score -1):

Methods in Java are bound to objects unless specified otherwise. For example, consider the function `foo(String str)` in the class `Bar`:

```
public class Bar {
    public void foo(String str) {
        doSomething(this);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This method is "attached" to a particular instance of the class `Bar`, meaning that it is effectively passed in as another parameter (e.g. like `foo(String str, Bar this)`). In Java, `this` is a reserved keyword, and refers tho this "hidden parameter".

Since this method has this hidden parameter, you **must** call it on an instance of `Bar`, for example:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.foo("hello");
```

If you just call: `Bar.foo()`, the "hidden parameter" does not know what it should be, and so this fails at compile time.

If, however, you do not need to refer to a particular instance during your method, you can mark it as `static`. This means you can call it on a class, rather than a type, like `Bar.foo();`

The error you are receiveing (non static method cannot be refernenced from a static context) is saying:

- you are trying to call a non-static method `facti(int i)` (or, with a "hidden parameter", `facti(int i, Facto facto)`).
- The context (i.e. the method you called it from: `public static void main(String[] args)`) is a **static** method, and so does not have this hidden parameter.

To fix it, either:

- Make your method `static`, to avoid the need for a particular instance of `Facto`
- Create an instance using `new Facto()`, and call it on that: e.g. `new Facto().facti(123);`

Comment: *Methods* are bound to *objects.*

Comment: Oops typo, ill edit